# PHP mail will not send from Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

I have two servers. One (linux) will send mail fine using the script below. The second (windows server 2008) sends nothing.

```
<?php mail ( "nobody@email.com", "Contact Us Form", "This is an email from your site", "From: nobody@email.com" )
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mail() works very different on linux and windows.

- On Linux it pipes your mail to the sendmail binary, which does all the work
- On windows it actually needs to act as an MTA to pass the mail off to another application.

On windows your best bet is to set the SMTP information so PHP can hand off the mail to another server which will take care of final delivery.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp

That done (and your webserver restarted to allow the change to take affect) if you're still unable to send mail check the logs for both PHP and the specified MTA to see where things are breaking down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question. I have about 5 files that send mail. Is it possible to have my SMTP info be something of a global file so I can just add one line of code to each file to enable my SMTP info be used for each mail file?

Comment: The settings in php.ini are global, so if you set them once all the PHP scripts run on that webserver will adopt them.

Comment: You'd be better off using PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They can hand email off to an SMTP server regardless of the platform they're on. Stick the config/auth information in a class and your various PHP scripts can reuse it all easily.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP.ini  You can also override these with the ini_set function at the script level (I think).

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
smtp_port = xx
```