# Php mail configuration error. Php send mail configuration

Tags: php

i have created php code for mail sending. but it not working. i am newbie. please help me in this error.pictue of error is given below.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>feedback email php</title>    
</head>
<body>
<form action="feedback.php" method="post">
<br>Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" size="30"> 
<br>Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="usermail" size="30">
<br>Message:<br>
<textarea name="feedback" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Sendmail">
</form>
</body>
</html>

//php file
<?php

$username=$_POST['username'];
$usermail=$_POST['usermail'];
$feedback=$_POST['feedback'];


$to="m.nawazchurahi001@gmail.com"; //we can replace email with our damain email
$sub="test mail";
$msg=$feedback;
ini_set('SMTP', "localhost");
ini_set('smtp_port', "25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', "m.nawazchurahi001@gmail.com");

mail($to,$sub,$msg);
echo "Thanks for your feedback";
echo "<br>";
echo "Message Receive from:";
echo $username;
echo "<br>";
echo "Reply to:";
echo $usermail;
?>
```

[This is error which i receiving on my chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R50Og.png)

[this is my php .ini file view.what me have to do for changing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLsQf.png)

Comment: Similar problem of using mail() on windows and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585445/php-mail-will-not-send-from-windows-server-2008

Comment: you have not seen my php.ini photo. my question were what me have to change there to resolve my issue.

Comment: What you have to set your SMTP details to is not a simple answer, Since you are using a Windows environment, you will have find an SMTP server to use and set the options in your PHP.ini correctly to that SMTP service. Windows has no built-in equivalent to sendmail like on *nix systems

Comment: i have resolve it,very simply